Stock trading backtest issues. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
I am running some code from the book 'Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading' 2nd Edition by Stefan Jansen, particularly in Ch. 5, Sec 2. 'backtest_with_pf_optimization' using a forked Github Repo in Visual Studio Code from the original source available here.
I keep running into an issue where I am unable to iterate over the results of a backtest in a DataFrame because the particular columns I want to iterate over are actually 'Series' objects instead of 'DataFrame'.
returns, positions, transactions = extract_rets_pos_txn_from_zipline(backtest)

returns the following error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3528/3074314327.py in ?()
----> 1 returns, positions, transactions = extract_rets_pos_txn_from_zipline(backtest)

~/.python/current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyfolio/utils.py in ?(backtest)
    151     if backtest.index.tzinfo is None:
    152         backtest.index = backtest.index.tz_localize('UTC')
    153     returns = backtest.returns
    154     raw_positions = []
--> 155     for dt, pos_row in backtest.positions.iteritems():
    156         df = pd.DataFrame(pos_row)
    157         df.index = [dt] * len(df)
    158         raw_positions.append(df)

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in ?(self, name)
   6292             and name not in self._accessors
   6293             and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   6294         ):
   6295             return self[name]
-> 6296         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

I have verified that each of the columns in questions are indeed 'Series' by running print(type(backtest['column_name'])) but I cannot understand why this occurring. Viewing the source documentation for the extract_rets_pos_txn_from_zipline() method (link) indicates that the expected output for returns, positions, transactions should be Series, DataFrame, DataFrame respectively.
I'm not sure why these particular objects are not being returned as DataFrame objects and it is preventing me from executing more of the files.
Is there a way to sort through this issue?
